# date is not changing though time cross midnight using as.POSIXct in r

Tags: r, lubridate

I have tried in this way to convert fraction number to date time

```
daytime = c("0.999259259259259", "0.000162037037037037","0.00106481481481481")

as.POSIXct(as.numeric((daytime)) * 24 * 60 * 60, origin = "2019-08-02 ", tz="GMT")
```

I am getting

```
"2019-08-02 23:58:56 GMT"  
"2019-08-02 00:00:14 GMT"  
"2019-08-02 00:01:32 GMT"
```

But I should get

```
"2019-08-02 23:58:56 GMT"  
"2019-08-03 00:00:14 GMT"   
"2019-08-03 00:01:32 GMT"
```

**daytime** is too large. I use 3 values for example here. I am looking for suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How else should these fractional dates evaluate? You add fractional dates < 1 to your origin. You probably want to add `+ 1` when you want a date one day later, don't you?

Comment: I am getting this fractional number from my excel file. In excel file time is in a proper format. So my question is after midnight the date should be changed but it is not happening here. Please can you clarify what do you mean by +1 @jay.sf? It will be helpful.

Comment: How can I know which time cross midnight?

Comment: I meant `as.POSIXct((as.numeric(daytime) + c(0, 1, 1))*24*60*60, origin="2019-08-02", tz="GMT")` would give the right solution. Probably your import method is flawed.

Comment: I want to mean when the time will be 00:00:00(midnight) then 2019-08-02 should be changed to 2019-08-03 like that 2019-08-03 will be changed to 2019-08-04. @Darren Tsai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `diff()` to identify when to enter a new day.

```
daytime = c("0.999259259259259", "0.000162037037037037","0.00106481481481481")
daytime <- as.numeric(daytime)

(new_day <- cumsum(c(F, diff(daytime) < 0)))
# [1] 0 1 1

as.POSIXct((daytime + new_day) * 24 * 60 * 60, "GMT", origin = "2019-08-02")

# [1] "2019-08-02 23:58:56 GMT"
# [2] "2019-08-03 00:00:14 GMT"
# [3] "2019-08-03 00:01:32 GMT"
```

Comment: This could be dangerous, as it is quite common for data not to be in the correct order. Anyway I like your solution +1

Comment: @jay.sf Yes you are right! The question doesn't provide enough information so I need to assume those times are in the correct order. Thanks for your reply!